# USB drives won't appear, flash drive appears fine

Tags: 16.04, usb, hard-drive, macbook-pro

I am new at using Linux.

A USB hard drive detached from the computer while it was on. Now the computer can't find the drive.

It will no longer appear anywhere on either the Ubuntu 16.04 or El Capitan 10.11.6 on a 2009 Macbook Pro. Neither will another USB hard drive I have. A flash drive Ubuntu LiveUSB I have will show up if I plug it in.

- I can't find the drives in Files or using GParted
- I can't find the drives if I boot into OS X
- I can't find the drives on another similar computer with a similar setup
- I can't find the drives in TestDisk

Other info

The computer was unable to boot into Ubuntu for a while after the drive detached. The internal hard drive sometimes disappears from the side toolbar, but the toolbar still has Files which still allows access to the internal drives.

- WD My Passport Ultra removable drive (detached unepectedly)
- Seagate Slim Portable Drive (other drive, did not detach)
- SanDisk USB 3.0 (discoverable LiveUSB)
- Macbook Pro Mid 2009 15 inch
- 2.53 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 8GB 1067 MHz DDR3
- El Capitan 10.11.6
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: it's possible the drive has been fryed. a normal test would have been to plug it in on another system but you already did that and it wasn't detected there so I'm prety sure the drive is dead.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is there a way I can recover the data?

Comment: Also, why would both be fried?

Comment: The second drive works now that I found a replacement chord for it.

Comment: on the USB? no I don't think so, not unless you're willing to pay a specialized data recoverer.